# Python - date tagging each line of a text file

Tags: python, date

I have a set of .txt files where the date of creation features in the filename, e.g. 'ab1900906cde.txt'. I want to tag each line within the file with that date. Helpfully each line begins with a common string while I'll refer to as 'xyz'.

I've written a code which captures the date and as I intended (confirmed by printing the date tag in line 10), but re.sub does not work to introduce the date tag into the output file. The code is:

```
mypath = 'users/mypath/'
myfiles = glob.glob(mypath + '*.txt')
for fin in myfiles:
    fn = os.path.basename(fin)
    fout = os.path.join(mypath + 'date_tagged_' + 'fn')
    yy = (fn[2:4])
    mm = (fn[4:6])
    dd = (fn[6:8])
    datetag = ("".join(['<Date: 20',yy,'-',mm,'-',dd,'>']))
    print(datetag)
    s = open(fin, encoding='utf8').read()
    s = re.sub('xyz', (datetag), s)
    with open(fout, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(s)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
s = re.sub('xyz', str(datetag), s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a little explanation to the answer:

Your code `datetag = ("".join(['<Date: 20',yy,'-',mm,'-',dd,'>']))` is actually a generator expression. Calling `str` on it materializes it into a string. You can also resolve this issue by removing the surrounding parenthesis, which are unnecessary. E.G. `datetag = "".join(['<Date: 20',yy,'-',mm,'-',dd,'>'])`.

Similarly, some of your other variable assignments are unnecessarily generator expressions:

```py
yy = (fn[2:4])
mm = (fn[4:6])
dd = (fn[6:8])
```

Can instead be

```py
yy = fn[2:4]
mm = fn[4:6]
dd = fn[6:8]
```